# Access Application from windows server not working through public ip

Tags: router, port-forwarding, home-networking

I have a application running on Port 3000 on a windows server 2019.

The access in the LAN works fine and now i want to access it also from internet, so i configured the port forwarding for the server on my fritzbox like this:[Port forwarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kUUy.png)

Now i tried to access via browser like this: 80.110.120.96:3000 (the ip is only an example, not the original one) -> no success (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT)

What i've tried so far: Mark the server on the fritzbox as "Exposed host" (so that all ports are open) and disabled the windows firewall on the server -> no success

I also disabled the IPv6, because i've read in some forums that that also causes problems... -> no success

Router model: Fritzbox 4040

Comment: Are you trying to access (pun intended) the database from your local network or from an external network?

Comment: i tried to access the application from both sides

Comment: ""Now i tried to access via browser like this: 80.110.120.96:3000"" where is that browser running?

Comment: the application is a nodejs app running on port 3000 and returns some json data...

Comment: on a client which is connected via WLAN, but also tried it via hotspot from outside.

Comment: I'm asking about the browser. What machine is it running on? Your local network or a machine on the public internet somewhere?

Comment: What does https://www.canyouseeme.org/ return?

Comment: local network, but i also tried it with one from the public internet, canyouseeme.rog returns "connection refused".

Comment: You are not port forwarding. Please read [Setting up MyFRITZ! accesses | FRITZ!Box 4040 | AVM International](https://en.avm.de/service/fritzbox/fritzbox-4040/knowledge-base/publication/show/1376_Setting-up-MyFRITZ-accesses/)

Comment: i configured it exactly the same way as in the article...

Comment: Your ISP could be blocking public facing servers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set port forwarding to the local IP address of your server, not your public IP, so that incoming traffic will reach your box, search for the local IP, be granted passage because you opened the right port, and you'll be able to access your server's content.

Comment: the port forwarding is configured to the local ip address

Comment: Is your public IP fixed?

Comment: that makes no difference, as i only want to access it for now to test.
It should be accessible with the public ip for now, as this one doesn't change each second...

Comment: True. You're certain of your setup on the server side: the app you want to reach is in a folder that's accessible to your user account on the laptop (?) you use from outside your network? If you're using a different account, does this account have permissions to access the folder where the app is? Have you tried a different software solution like OpenVNC? EDIT: did you reboot your router/box after enabling port-forwarding? Sometimes it makes a lot of difference. (Sorry about the lengthy troubleshooting: I'm a Help Desk Technician by trade. Old habits die hard...

Comment: Also: your app requires an environment to run, right? Is this environment running at all times on your server? If not, accessing the app from outside your network is one thing, launch it, along with all its dependencies is another. EDIT: and of course, your firewall allows inbound traffic on port 3000?

Comment: no problem :)  from the application side + from the firwall side nothing is blocked, as i disabled fully to except these things

Comment: I should have begun my questioning by that, but I assumed (wrongly?) that it was the first thing you tried: have you activated the Remote Access role in your server management interface?